# How can I update the status of a Test

Tags: c#-4.0, versionone

We are automating tests using selenium, and I would like to be able to update the test to their latest status based on the result of the automated test.

I'm able to identify the test, but it appears the Status property does not have a setter.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the Object Model library.

The Object Model library does not, in fact, have a setter for that property. It may expect you to use an Operation on that asset to adjust status, such as `.Close()`

The [SDK API library](http://v1appcatalog.azurewebsites.net/app/index.html#/Details/VersionOne.SDK.NET.APIClient) has more fine-grained access and allows more arbitrary asset editing.  You may also hit the [`rest-1.v1` API endpoint](http://legacy.community.versionone.com/sdk/Documentation/DataAPI.aspx#intro) directly with an XML body describing your attribute change.  You'd need to know the ID of the `TestStatus` list item you want to set it to, and do a [single-valued relation update](http://legacy.community.versionone.com/sdk/Documentation/DataAPI.aspx#lbe.update.relation)

Do you have code you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Once I have a VersionOne.SDK.ObjectModel.Test object I was able to do the following:

```
Test test = null;
test = FindTest(regressionTest); // This finds the Test object.
test.Status.CurrentValue = status; 
test.Save();
```